# How can I construct the right chord from one array per piano key?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, return-value

I currently have an array that holds the 12 major scales in music(keyList). I need a way of looping through the array and returning the chord that the user enters without hardcoding a bunch of chords into my program. For example, if the user enters the string ceg, the program would respond with: "You entered C-E-G, the Cmajor chord". My problem is in my constructChord function. I can't return 3 separate indexes for my keyList array, so I need a way of forming a new string from my array based on the string the user enters?.. If I need to be more specific or clarify, let me know, but any help would be appreciated.

Github:[ChordQuiz-Program](https://github.com/phil-03/pianoChords/blob/master/piano_chords.cpp)

Edit: I've never posted here before, and tried to make it specific. If it's still a bad question just tell me. Even better, tell me why...

Comment: You probably want a type that represents a chord. It's also probably better to represent a chord as a collection of intervals, not notes in a string. Then a major chord is `{root, major third, perfect fifth}`regardless of key.

Comment: That would definitely make it easier with everything being less granular. A lot less to work with. But then the user input would be according to the number system, so 1 - 3 - 5 instead of C - E -G for example right? How would you differentiate between major chords if not via string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My problem is in my constructChord function. I can't return 3 separate indexes for my keyList array**

I really hop I understood that right?

Yes you can! With c++11 it´s easy, with c++17 it´s magic. I´m using int for my example ´cause you used int but nearly all types can be tupled.

### c++11

```
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, int, int> Music::constructChord(ChordType chord)
{
    // do something to calculate int a, b, c
    return std::make_tuple(a, b, c);   // just an example of course 
}
```

### c++17

```
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, int, int> Music::constructChord(ChordType chord)
{
    // do something to calculate int a, b, c
    return {a, b, c};   // that is really cool, isn´t it? 
}
```

### Sanitizing and tupleing the input

Here´s a quick hack example of how the input could be sanitized and tupleed. I´ve put in a main() so it can directly be compiled and played with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    // this map is only a stub of course, a lot is missing ...
    std::map<std::string, int> sanitation = {{"a",0}, {"bb",1}, {"c",2}, {"c#",3}, {"#c",3}, {"db",3},  {"bd",3}};

    // input block from your code
    std::string myChord;
    std::cout << "Please enter a chord, at least three different piano keys:\n";
    getline(std::cin, myChord);
    transform(myChord.begin(), myChord.end(), myChord.begin(), ::tolower);

    // parsing the input
    std::regex regex(  R"(([a-g#]{1,2}) ([a-g#]{1,2}) ([a-g#]{1,2}))");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(myChord, m, regex);

    // sanitizing und tupleing it
    std::vector<int> matched;
    for (int i=1; i<m.size(); i++)
    {
        auto hit = sanitation.find(m[i]);
        if(hit!=sanitation.end())
            matched.push_back(hit->second);
    }

    auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple(matched);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I know my wording was a bit confusing. But I had no idea I could do this, really cool. I'll do more research on it, but now I am tasked with figuring out how to apply those return values to compare with what the user enters. Would you recommend an int enum ? So what every the three return values are would be the the constructed chord, in that order....

Comment: I could create a tuple of the user input? Interesting... And my array is setup the same way the keys are aligned on a piano. So, 0-3-7 (a minor)and 3-7-10.(Cmajor).

Comment: opps, yes, dunno what i did my counting was messed up. But usually you start with c being 0, don´t you? But it doesn´t matter. Regarding parsing the input: I think that is what I would do. You need to sanitize the input anyway, dont you? What if the user enter C of c? Or fb for e or gb for dM chord? Or ab instead ba (like its written on the staff). That are things that I would like to sanitize. And later you´ll want to add more keys and M7 and stuff, thats easier if you parse the input, isn´t it`?

Comment: btw. one suggestion for input sanitation: would be to use a std::map

Comment: Cool, what I'm currently doing is lowercasing the input as I receive them, so it will match everything in my array. But you are right I need to sanitize a bit more for additional items. I will definitely check out std::map too. Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: @pj03 hey I've added a code example to show what I mean to my answer. And if it was useful, please remember to think about upvoting it or accepting the answer (or both :-)

Comment: you were very helpful and I appreciate all you've done. I don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but your answer was definitely accepted.